# Why does canvas context drawImage fail on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, html, image, canvas

The objective is to have the users choice of photograph displayed on both the image and canvas elements.

Why does this code work on Firefox, Chrome, IE, iPad but not on iPhone?  On iPhone 3GS or iPhone 5 the canvas (red border) is simply shown blank albeit the correct size.

It does seem to work for iPhone screen captures but not photographs.  Web Inspector gives us nothing.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body{font-size:120%;}        
    #diag{ font-family:'Courier New';}
    img{border:2px solid blue;}
    canvas{border:2px solid red;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var prev;
    function go() {
        prev = new Date();
        diag('');
        diag('start');
        var imgFile = document.getElementById('submitfile');
        if (imgFile.files && imgFile.files[0]) {
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            diag('reader.onloadend');
            diag('reader.result.length=' + (reader.result.length / 1024.0 / 1024.0).toFixed(4) + "mb");
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
              diag('img.onload');
              var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
              var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
              diag("img.width:" + this.width);
              diag("img.height:" + this.height);
              cvs.width = this.width;
              cvs.height = this.height;
              diag("cvs.width:" + cvs.width);
              diag("cvs.height:" + cvs.height);
              ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
              ctx.font = '18pt Calibri';
              ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
              ctx.fillText('CANVAS COPY', 100, 100);
              document.body.appendChild(cvs); // new canvas
              document.body.appendChild(this); // img element
              diag('ctx.drawImage');
            };
            img.src = reader.result;
        }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile.files[0]);
        diag('reader.readAsDataURL');
    }
    function diag(msg) {
        var now = new Date();
        var ms = now.getTime() - prev.getTime();
        var current_diag_text = document.getElementById("diag").innerHTML;
        var new_diag_text = ms + "ms " + msg + "<br/>" + current_diag_text;
        if (msg === '') {
        document.getElementById("diag").innerHTML = '';
        } else {
        document.getElementById("diag").innerHTML = new_diag_text;
        }
        prev = now;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Upload" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p id="diag"></p>
    <p>Choose Photo: <input type="file" name="submitfile" id = "submitfile" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="go();" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

We've now learnt of two issues here, one is a memory limitation of mobile safari described at https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15.  This can be overcome by adding portions of the image to canvas rather than all in one go.  The next limitation is a problem with mobile safari scaling the resulting canvas image incorrectly.

Both of these issues are avoided by using the excellent mega pixel image rendering library @ https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel.

Answer (score -2):

As to my knowledge above given Script is not even working on IPad